# Cannot create DOMdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I cannot create a new DOMdocument using:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
```

The output is just empty. Not an empty object like `DOMDocument Object( )`, but completely empty. Usually it should be an object like:

```
DOMDocument Object
(
    [doctype] => 
    [implementation] => (object value omitted)
    [documentElement] => 
    [actualEncoding] => 
    [encoding] => 
    [xmlEncoding] => 
    [standalone] => 1
    [xmlStandalone] => 1
    [version] => 1.0
    [xmlVersion] => 1.0
    [strictErrorChecking] => 1
    [documentURI] => 
    [config] => 
    [formatOutput] => 
    [validateOnParse] => 
    [resolveExternals] => 
    [preserveWhiteSpace] => 1
    [recover] => 
    [substituteEntities] => 
    [...]
)
```

I'm using PHP version 5.6.7 and `phpinfo()` says:

> DOM/XML: enabled
>   DOM/XML API Version: 20031129
>   libxml Version: 2.9.2`

There is other PHP code on the server / in the script, so I can say that PHP is running normally. Any advice what the next steps should be to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    var_dump($dom);
?>
```

output:

```
object(DOMDocument)#1 (34) { ["doctype"]=> NULL ["implementation"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["documentElement"]=> NULL ["actualEncoding"]=> NULL ["encoding"]=> NULL ["xmlEncoding"]=> NULL ["standalone"]=> bool(true) ["xmlStandalone"]=> bool(true) ["version"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["xmlVersion"]=> string(3) "1.0" ["strictErrorChecking"]=> bool(true) ["documentURI"]=> NULL ["config"]=> NULL ["formatOutput"]=> bool(false) ["validateOnParse"]=> bool(false) ["resolveExternals"]=> bool(false) ["preserveWhiteSpace"]=> bool(true) ["recover"]=> bool(false) ["substituteEntities"]=> bool(false) ["nodeName"]=> string(9) "#document" ["nodeValue"]=> NULL ["nodeType"]=> int(9) ["parentNode"]=> NULL ["childNodes"]=> string(22) "(object value omitted)" ["firstChild"]=> NULL ["lastChild"]=> NULL ["previousSibling"]=> NULL ["attributes"]=> NULL ["ownerDocument"]=> NULL ["namespaceURI"]=> NULL ["prefix"]=> string(0) "" ["localName"]=> NULL ["baseURI"]=> NULL ["textContent"]=> string(0) "" }
```

refer: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Unfortunately that does not change anything.